# How to get field value after distincting with foreinkey

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, distinct

I'm beginner in Djanog and trying to display values that distinct result with `foreinkey`.
Here are my env and example model.

- Django 1.8
- Mysql5
- Python2.7

  ```
  class a_group(models.Model):
      num = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.title

  class b_group(models.Model):
      no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      group = models.ForeignKey(a_group)
  ```

And then I tried to distinct with group field like this.

```
g = b_group.objects.values('group').distinct()
```

But, as mentioned at here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values , it only return pk, not title.

Is there anyway to get title field value also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also refer to fields on related models with reverse relations through **OneToOneField**,**ForeignKey** and **ManyToManyField** attributes, you can do as follow:

```
g = b_group.objects.values('group__title').distinct()
```

to access a field of related model Django use by convention double underscore.